# difference in dts development over ssis development

Tags: ssis, dts

I have been using ssis in my past project.//in the coming project we are going to use dts.Is there any differnce between ssis and dts in developer point of view.Just want to know about dts development from someboy ,who had worked in dts
hilsen

Comment: I have used both. SSIS is the evolution of DTS. They are very similar, but, as you'd expect, SSIS is more refined and more powerful than DTS.

Comment: Thanks.Is it very difficult to develop in dts ? what would be the reason ,the project would not allow to use ssis instead of dts?

Comment: Well, whether you can use SSIS or DTS is determined by the version of SQL Server being used. SQL Server version 7 and 2000 came with DTS.  Starting with SQL Server 2005, SSIS was availble, as long as you had the "Developer", "Standard", or "Enterprise" versions of the product.

Comment: Is there any DTS service available in sql server 2012?.The project work is on migrating the data from sql 2000 to sql 2012.Why can not they use sql server 2012 ssis to do this?

Comment: I don't know of any reason why you could not connect a SQL Server 2012 SSIS package to a SQL Server 2000 database.  I would think that approach would be preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been about 8 years since I've dealt with DTS but the major, fundamental difference in my mind is that DTS is far more flexible with your source data. SSIS requires a tight binding between source data types and quantity of columns. DTS is much more casual and can respond to anything. This flexibility comes with a performance cost. I have no hard numbers but in my experience it can be considerable.

### Supported languages

DTS supported any ActiveX language. That usually translated to VBScript but we used the ActivePython implementation as Python's a more elegant language (no citation needed). SSIS in 2005 only supported VB.NET 2008 forward supports C# and VB.NET

### Invocation

DTS could be compiled down to a .VBS file which allowed you to write an ETL thing that could run on any machine that VB could run on. There's no such option for SSIS. An SSIS is a XML file that is fed into .NET libraries which perform some actions. While that sounds like an "it can run anywhere scenario", the *licensing* requires it to run on a machine with SQL Server installed.

### Support

DTS is dead. Super, mega extended support for SQL Server 2000 expired in April of 2013. If you have a problem with a SQL Server 2000 instance, unless you're a Fortune 5 company **and** plan on spending a sizable chunk of money on it, you're on your own to resolve any problem you encounter.

Along those lines, good luck finding folks with a current DTS skillset to support whatever you develop.

### Error handling

At least I think it was error handling, my brain is not as sharp as it once was. But, I think we had trouble getting a Transform Data Task to handle bad data as expected. Something related to error handling was well neigh impossible to make work as expected.

### Tooling

SSIS uses a Visual Studio extension commonly referred to as BIDS (Business Intelligence Designer Studio (2005-2008R2)) or SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools-BI (2012+)). DTS is designed in Enterprise Manager which was a thing for SQL Server 7.0/2000.

Answer (score 0):

From a developer's perspective, there is little difference between SSIS and DTS. SSIS contains a larger and richer feature set than DTS.